# MediaFoundation - How to encode audio to MP3 straight from capture device into another bytestream?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, encode, ms-media-foundation

I can record audio using MediaFoundation, but it only gives me a PCM Wave buffer. I want to grab the full buffer, encode it to MP3, and then use the new buffer for networking stuff.

What is the right way to encode the audio after receiving the samples? I have gotten lost reading through MediaSession, MediaSinks, SinkWriter, Transcode API, Transform API, Source Resolver, etc.

I see there is an [MP3 encoder object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mp3-audio-encoder), but I cant find the documentation on how to use it. I also found an [MP3 MediaSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemp3mediasink) but im not sure how the MediaSink fits in with the SourceReader / SinkWriter schema or how to create/use the IMFByteStream it requires.

Is the MediaFoundation the right WinAPI for the task?

Comment: You could try to use [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) `MediaFoundationEncoder class` can be used to convert WAV files into other formats such as WMA, AAC and MP3. You could refer to the link: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/MediaFoundationEncoder.md